# Listar datas calculadas por mês com base em parâmetros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Com base em duas datas recebidas por parâmetro, estou a tentar listar todas as datas por mês (uma data por mês) com base na data de início e até à data de fim. Estas datas devolvidas tem de verificar qual o dia da semana da data de início e o número da semana, para assim replicar essa data para todos os meses.

Por exemplo, `@StartDate = 2016/04/15` e `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`, verifico que a `@StartDate` é na numa primeira sexta-feira do Abril, então até à `@EndDate` iria datas para todas as primeiras sexta-feira de cada mês:

```
2016/05/06
2016/06/03
2016/07/01
2016/08/05
```

Para o caso de `@StartDate = 2016/04/12` e `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`, verifico que a `@StartDate` é na segunda terça-feira do mês de Abril, ia então buscar todas as segundas terças-feira de cada mês:

```
2016/05/10
2016/06/14
2016/07/12
2016/08/09
```

Para o caso de `@StartDate = 2016/04/28` e `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`, verifico que a `@StartDate` é na última semana à quinta-feira do mes de Abril:

```
2016/05/26
2016/06/30
2016/07/28
2016/08/25
```

Neste último caso teria de ter em atenção o número de semanas de cada mês, visto que há meses com 4 e outro com 5 semanas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma CTE recursiva para gerar a lista de datas do período e depois filtrar as datas que correspondem ao mesmo dia da semana e o número da semana no mês seja o mesmo da data de início.

```
declare @startDate date;
declare @endDate date;

declare @weekday int;
declare @weekmonth int;

select @startDate = '2016/02/15';
select @endDate = '2016/09/13';

select @weekday = DATEPART(dw,@startDate), -- dia da semana
    @weekmonth = DATEPART(day,@startDate)/7 + 1; -- número da semana no mês


;with dateRange as
(
  select dt = dateadd(dd, 1, @startDate)
  where dateadd(dd, 1, @startDate) < @endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, dt)
  from dateRange
  where dateadd(dd, 1, dt) < @endDate
)
select *
from dateRange 
where DATEPART(dw,dt) = @weekday
    and (DATEPART(day,dt)-1)/7 + 1 = @weekmonth
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Parece ir um pouco ao encontro do que quero, mas por exemplo, se inserir na `@starDate = '2016/02/01'` acaba por ir buscar apenas as segunda-feira na primeira semana dos meses, e no mês de Março (por exemplo) não existe 2ªf na primeira semana. Queria conseguir retornar então a primeira 2ªf no mês

Comment: Corrigi o cálculo da variável @weekmonth para retornar o número da semana correspondente à data de início.

Comment: @rocodleiv exato, acaba é por não funcionar para em dias no final do mês. O exemplo de escolher a `@startDate = '2016/03/31';`, é a última quinta feira do mês (nesta caso Março), para os próximos meses tem de ir buscar a última quinta feira do mes, tendo ou não o dia 31

Comment: Realmente, há muitos critérios a serem considerados. Acredito que seja mais fácil você ter uma tabela de Datas [exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7134280/1653643), com campos pré-calculados ("último dia da semana no mês", "número da semana no mês" etc).

Answer (score 1):

Aqui fica a solução:

```
set @NumSemana = datepart(day, datediff(day, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@StartDate), 0), @StartDate)/7 * 7)/7 + 1;
WITH    AllDays
  AS ( SELECT  @StartDate  AS [Date], DATEPART(month, @StartDate) as validMonth
       UNION ALL
       SELECT   DATEADD(week, 1, [Date]), 
                iif(DATEPART(month,DATEADD(week, 1, [Date])) < validMonth + @PeriodicityRepeat, validMonth, validMonth + @PeriodicityRepeat)
       FROM     AllDays
       WHERE    
            DATEPART(month,[Date]) <= DATEPART(month,@EndDate)
        and DATEPART(year,[Date]) <= DATEPART(year,@EndDate)
            ),
rankedDays 
  AS(     
    SELECT [Date], validMonth, 
           row_number() over ( partition by DATEPART( month, [Date]) order by [Date]) ascOrder,
           row_number() over ( partition by DATEPART( month, [Date]) order by [Date] desc) descOrder
    FROM   AllDays 
    WHERE DATEPART(month, [Date]) = validMonth
)
select [Date]
from rankedDays
where ((ascOrder = @NumSemana and @NumSemana <=4 )  
        or (descOrder = 1 and @NumSemana = 5) 
        or [Date] = @StartDate )
   and [Date] < @EndDate 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `DATENAME` passando o `weekday` para retorna o nome da semana `varchar` e  `DATEPART`  passando o `weekday` para retorna a semana em um `int`

```
declare @StartDate datetime = 2016/01/15

SELECT DATENAME(weekday,  @StartDate)  -- Retorna o nome da semana varchar
SELECT DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) -- Retorna a semana int 




declare @StartDate datetime = getdate();

WITH CTE_PastYearinWeeks
AS (
select
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()-365), 0) as DateStart
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(WK,DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate),DateStart)
FROM CTE_PastYearinWeeks
WHERE DATEADD(WK,DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate),DateStart) <= GETDATE()
)
select  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DateStart, 107),1,6) as WeekTitle
from CTE_PastYearinWeeks
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Obrigado Marco, mas não é isso que pretendo

Comment: Verdade, basta adaptar ai... vou ter que sair aqui... só faltou validar a data de inicio e fim... depois termino

Comment: Ainda assim parece não estar a calcular bem o dia e a semana para ir buscar a data

Comment: Acredito que a resposta do ricidleiv tem o que você precisa.

Comment: Queria fazer algo como está neste link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32508/How-to-Use-SQL-Server-to-Select-Records-for-a-Sche
no "Monthly (Frequency Type 4)":
http://s30.postimg.org/ihy6mc6lt/image.png